# Ruby Version Error while deploying app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy Ruby on Rails application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am getting following error -

```
ERROR: [Instance: <Instance ID>] Command failed on instance. Return code: 18 Output: (TRUNCATED)...e ']'
+ bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Your Ruby version is 2.4.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.3.
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) '<Instance ID>'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

After I got this error, I had deleted ruby version number from Gemfile but still I was getting this error.

After that I deployed app in a new Beanstalk environment without any mention of Ruby version in Gemfile. But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I dont use Beanstalk, but make sure your Gemfile.lock is still not showing old ruby version. Do a bundle install to refresh it.

Comment: I had tried that but no success.

Comment: Please post your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am getting same problem

Comment: @NomuraNori did anyone here solve this.  My ruby version is the latest but telling me its the older one...? and won't get onto aws deplyoemnt

Comment: Same here, still having this issue. Pleas shed a light if you've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was deleted because I gave a similar answer to another question asking about issues with outdated and insecure versions of Ruby, but I will reiterate the same advice I would give to anyone running into errors using an insecure version of Ruby like 2.4.3: update to 3+ or at least 2.7 and the corresponding compatible Bundler version.

Note to Admins: if this answer is worthy of deletion, please delete this question as well and ask the user to repost with a supported Ruby version.